# NoSuchMethodError : The method 'map' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Sometimes animals.relatives is empty and so t.name returns null which is causing the problem

I tried if else statements and try catch but it doesn't work inside the widget i guess ? i'm not sure why it didn't work

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(animals.name),
    Text(animals.desc),
    Text("Relatives :"),
    Row(
      children: animals.relatives.map((t) => 
        FilterChip(
          label: Text(t.name),onSelected: (b){}))
         .toList(),
     ),
   ]),
```

I want the row and text above it not to show if t.name is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **collection-if** for this:

```dart
..,
children: <Widget>[
 ..,
 Text('Relatives: '),
 if (animals.relatives != null &&
     animals.relatives.isNotEmpty &&
     animals.relatives.where((t) => t != null).isNotEmpty)
   Row(
     children: animals.relatives.where((t) => t != null).map(..).toList(),
   ),
],
```

This ensures that the `Row` is only included when your variable is *neither null nor empty*.
**Additionally**, all elements that are `null` are excluded from the list and the `Row` is not built when there are only `null` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works only on Row(), but i want the text above it not to show too if it's null